# Surface Pro 5 infinite boot loop issue

Tags: windows-10, boot, microsoft-surface-pro

My surface suddenly won't boot. After pressing a power button, it shows a Windows Logo and turns off.

1. Volume-Up + Power button not working
2. USB Recovery inserted + Volume-Down + Power button not working
3. Boot + F2 (repeatedly pressing) not working
4. Boot + F8 (repeatedly pressing) not working
5. Boot + F12 (repeatedly pressing) not working

Here is the video: https://youtu.be/2UuW70r3mAY

I didn't found any similiar problem on internet. Do anyone have an idea what's the problem with it ?

Comment: Does it boot into Safe Mode?  Shut down, start up, press F8 repeatedly and see if it starts.  Can you start with a bootable USB Key to see if it starts that way.

Comment: No, F8, F2, F12 is not registered while booting, I can't go further than the flashing logo.

Comment: May be that the disk drive has failed.

Comment: I'm trying the last chance, to fully discharge the battery, by pressing the power button. Hope it will clear the CMOS, RAM or something.

Comment: This is resolved by pressing the power button for hours to discharge the battery - I can confirm it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

My Surface Pro 7 did the same. Trying to fix by continuously powering on the device until the battery dies. (following this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef8AOXycZm8&list=PLNgJJI6FeVDSUKVejJZsjwWnBGHA_lJw8&index=2)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).