# How to fix Surface Pro 7 stuck in boot loop?

Tags: windows-10, boot, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm trying to fix a Surface Pro 7 with Windows 10 that is stuck in a boot loop.

It tries to start, flashes up the Windows logo, then quits and restarts again. And again. And again...

Hard reboot holding down the power button doesn't help.

I saw in another post ([Surface Pro 5 infinite boot loop issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1662523/surface-pro-5-infinite-boot-loop-issue)) that pressing the power button a lot to discharge the battery can fix it.

I'm trying to drain the battery by plugging in a USB powered desk lamp. Will it have the same effect?

And does anyone know what causes this condition in the first place?

Comment: 1. It's doubtful you'd be able to discharge the battery enough to do anything; there are protection circuits. Further, complete discharge can damage the battery. 2. Can't you enter Safe mode after holding power button 3 times? 3. Make USB Windows 10 installation, go to to BIOS/UEFI setup, boot from installation media and repair.

Comment: Have you try with power button and volume up for 10 seconds?

Comment: Yeah, tried that. No luck :(

Comment: FYI, I have had limited success with draining the battery to fix this. On some devices, leaving them running overnight seems to drain the battery, then plugging the device back into a charger brings them back to life. But on other devices, I can't get it to come back to life after draining the battery. I'm not what the difference is.