# Surface Pro 7 plus corrupt SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, microsoft-surface

I'm working as a Level 1 IT help desk in a High School. We exclusively use MS Surface devices for the students. I have a student device I'm struggling with. It's a Surface Pro 7 Plus which shows the Windows logo on startup, then shows a blue screen of death, then reboots again. It's also getting very hot during all this. If I hold down the power button, I can get it to shut down. I think I'll need to get a replacement device (it's still under warranty), but I want to try and save the students data before I do that.

I have taken out the SSD (256mb) hoping to save some data, but when I put it into a cradle thing and plug it into another Windows device and look in the Disk Management app, it just says "Unknown. Not initialised".

This looks to me like I have a corrupt SSD on my hands, but I'm hoping somebody can suggest something I can do to save this students data.

I did post a similar question recently ([How to fix Surface Pro 7 stuck in boot loop?](https://superuser.com/questions/1805433/how-to-fix-surface-pro-7-stuck-in-boot-loop)) about how to get a Surface device out of a similar boot loop, but I don't think that is possible in this case, so I'm looking for how I can rescue the data on the SSD.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the cradle, it’s probably not compatible, with your SSD. Honestly, the SSD likely has failed in some way, so there probably isn’t anything you can do but this problem is difficult to diagnose without any detailed diagnosis information

Comment: Encrypted? If you view using hex editor, do you see data, random gibberish?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen encryption is unlikely, but you never know what students get up to ;)

Comment: @Ramhound I think we have another cradle around here. I can try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Even if it was encrypted. The volume would be detected y Windows. You just couldn’t mount the volume.  **Encryption isn’t the reason for the behavior.**